# Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) code -6 (Leon, Moto E, Grand Prime (Snapdragon 410))

Tags: android, crash-dumps

My app crashes upon startup whenever I test it on phones that have the Snapdragon 410 chipset. I have dozens of reports of this happening to end-users and all of them so far come have from devices that use the Snapdragon 410 chipset. I went out and purchased two Snapdragon 410 phones (Moto E, LG Leon) and both of them exhibit the crash. So far, testing on other devices sees no crash occur.

Here is the log:

```
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9447 (com.myapp)
Build fingerprint: 'lge/c50_tmo_us/c50:5.1.1/LMY47V/151671737ee07:user/release-keys'
Revision: '8'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 9447, tid: 9447, name: com.myapp  >>> com.myapp <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
  r0 00000000  r1 000024e7  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
AM write failure (32 / Broken pipe)
  r4 b6f70e38  r5 00000006  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
  r8 a10724a1  r9 becdf520  sl 00100c12  fp 00100c0e
  ip 000024e7  sp becdf498  lr b6df804d  pc b6e1f648  cpsr 600d0010
backtrace:
  #00 pc 0003b648  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
  #01 pc 00014049  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
  #02 pc 00014c67  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
  #03 pc 000114e1  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
  #04 pc 0000f72c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
  #05 pc 00049fbd  /system/lib/libc++.so
  #06 pc 000491b5  /system/lib/libc++.so (__clear_cache+32)
  #07 pc 00002a21  /data/data/bn.ereader/files/libcrashreport.so (deleted)
Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_00
```

I have isolated the crash trigger to an external library jar which I bundle with my app; when I remove the external jar (and my code that invokes it by calling externalLibrary.init()), the crash does not occur. Since I do not have the source code for the external jar, I do not yet know the root cause of the problem.

The framework's crash handler plops a tombstone, but my device is not rooted and I haven't been able to recover the tombstone yet. I might try rooting the device to make the tombstone pluckable.

Comment: you should be able to access /data/tombstone without root. It could be the fact the external jar is not built for Lollipop SDK? This question is not suitable for this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on android.stackexchange.com

Comment: This is a developer question, not an end-user / power-user question. Developers are going to run into this issue, and they will come here to get answers. I have already provided a partial answer by explaining that the bug occurs only on certain chipsets. Hopefully someone will chime in and give a root cause.

Comment: Hi, Joseph! I've just run into the same problem and most of devices are on Snapdragon 410 too (Samsung Galaxy E5 and Galaxy Core Prime). Could you please point which external library was guilty in your case. Thanks.

Comment: In my case it was Apptimize. I asked them to explain the source of the problem; their response was basically "we found an Android API that doesn't work on certain architectures and stopped invoking it" (they didn't tell me which API). If your app is crashing upon startup, I suggest you examine the onCreate() methods for Application and Activities; comment out code until the app works.